# Excel file to exe (xls to exe)

Tags: excel, exe, vba

Is it possible convert xlsx sheet with macro to exe file without opening excel? I try some converters but all open excel.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by converting xls file to exe, and still do not want to open excel? @Fiinek?

Comment: I want to block menu and all function for editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paste the code in a notepad and save as VBS file. Also change the filepath and macro name. It starts with a user confirmation.

```
Option Explicit

Dim xlApp, xlBook
dim x


x=msgbox("Do You want to run the macro",4+64+0+4096,"Confirmation...")

if x= vbyes then

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'~~> Change Path here to your excel file
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Deb\Desktop\contactlist2.xlsm", 0, True)

'~~> Change macro name

xlApp.Run "check_data" 

xlbook.save

xlBook.Close

xlApp.Quit

Set xlBook = Nothing

Set xlApp = Nothing

WScript.Echo "Finished."

WScript.Quit

end if
```

Answer (score 2):

For this,you can try to run macro from outside excel like given below -

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Application.Run "'full path to excel file'!module name.macro name"
objExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
objExcel.Application.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

[enter link description here](http://wellsr.com/vba/2015/excel/run-macro-without-opening-excel-using-vbscript/)

**To open a read-only workbook, try adding the following line right before your objExcel.Application.Run line**

Set book = objExcel.Workbooks.Open('full path to excel file',,TRUE)

Comment: and for full sheet ?

Comment: Please check link. it's given there how to open workbook in read only mode.

Comment: If this answer is useful for you please mark it as answer.